# How do you force Ember to rerender a component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an Ember component that uses jQuery to add a canvas chart.  When I change routes, I get a new model, but Ember's automatic rerendering does not work in this case.  In fact, I don't know how to make the component code which adds the chart re-run at all.  How can I do this?

Would it work better if it was a view?

Comment: What code are you using to render the chart in the first place?  Is it on `init`?  It sounds like you need to observe the model as well, and when the model changes run that code again.  Views are being deprecated, component is the way to go.

Comment: I have it run on InsertElement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without looking at code, I'm going to guess based on your statement of the model changing.

#### Component Currently

```
uiSetup: function(){
   // do magic here...
}.on('didInsertElement')
```

#### Component with observes

Assuming the model in the component is named model, this would fire every time the model changed as well as when the element was initially inserted into the page.  You could also break it into two separate functions if you need it to act differently on model change vs element inserted first time.

```
uiSetup: function(){
   // do magic here...
}.on('didInsertElement').observes('model')
```

Comment: In Ember 1.13.0 you have new lifecycle hooks available that allow you to not use `observer` (they're kinda heavy perf-wise): http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_component-lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Those hooks don't apply to this answer.

Comment: The hooks that @locks suggested do work if the attributes are bound. I use this with the <img> element as a component so that the image can be sized dynamically ```<img src={{url}} style={{myStyle}}>``` in the didRecieveAttrs hook I update the style attribute with the bound myStyle string. Note: style updates must be sanitized: ```Ember.String.htmlSafe(styleString)```.